# Should I be concerned of Over-Optimism in Nested Cross Validation with Multiple Scoring Criteria?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, descriptive-statistics, overfitting

Suppose I am using Nested CV to estimate the generalized error of a model and a set of hyperparameters.  I have chosen two scoring metrics of interest: Brier Score and AUC, because I want to get an idea of how discriminative and calibrative my model is.

---

Because my associated cost requires good calibration, I want to choose/estimate a model with the best brier score. This of course means that *within the inner loop* I am going to return the hyperparameter configuration that corresponds to the highest brier score, do this for all outer folds as a validation step, and compute a generalized error.  **I save this error, and I will then perform vanilla cross validation on the entire data set to 'recover' the optimal hyperparameters (I report the general error as the error of my model and discard the cv scores here**

*Now, I want to return the hyperparameter configuration within the inner cv fold that maximizes the brier score. But because I care about AUC also, I collect all the hyperparameters configurations that correspond to brier scores within one standard deviation of the maximum brier score and choose the one with the highest auc.*

I am familiar with the concept of nested cv for a particular socring rule.  However, my concern is that I am introducing selection bias and biasing the reported scores

---

**My Question is: are my reported errors optimistic by including a second scoring statistic within my model building process ?**

Should I do something like:

1. Triple cv?, where within the inner loop of a standard cv I nest
   another single loop that selects the best auc configuration?
2. Independant Nested CVs for my two scoring rules to estimate generalized
   error wrt to a single error metric.  I then refit on the entire data,
   perform vanilla cv, return all hyperconfigurations within one std
   deviation of the max brier score, and then choose the one with the
   highest auc

I should disclaim that most of my confusion is coming from the 'refit' parameter in sklearn, I am not sure if the one standard error rule is being applied within the nested cv structure.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Nested CV is not a model-selection procedure. It does not return hyperparameters. It is a method to estimate a generalization error of a model-selection procedure. It does not matter how you decide to choose your model/tune your hyperparameters in the inner loop.

Just run it once to get an estimate of your generalization error, and then run exactly the same inner loop on the whole dataset to get your final model.

You will need to decide in advance if you would like to use the Brier Score, the AUC, or a combination (you could go for a weighted average or use a model with the highest Brie in a certain quantile of AUC or anything you can dream up) to tune the hyperparameters and then do it exactly in the same way when fitting the final model.